# a possible generalization of Hilbert 90 theorem

Tags: polynomials, homological-algebra

$L/K$ is a finite Galois extension with group $G$.
Let $F \in K[X]$ a separable monic polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$ and consider the $L$-algebra $B=L[X]/\langle F \rangle$.
Coefficients of $F$ are in $K$ and we can define a natural action of $G$ on $B$.
Is it true that we have:

\begin{equation}
H^1(G,B^\times)=\{1\}
\end{equation}

where $B^\times$ is the group of inversibles of $B$.
Is there an elementary proof of that result ?

NB: if $F=X$ then $B=L$ and we have the Hilbert 90 classical theorem.

Comment: In _An Introduction to Galois Cohomology and its Applications_, G. Berhuy proves in proposition III.8.24 that for any semi-simple $K$-algebra $A$, and any Galois extension $L/K$, one has $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(L/K) ; (A \otimes_K L)^{\times}) = 1$.

Since the coefficients of $F$ are in $K$, we may define $A = K[X] / (F)$ so that $A \otimes_K L = B$.